# mex implementation of a project on matlab

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I am trying to compile C files from a project present [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vedaldi/code/mser.html")

Iam working with matlab R2013a on win 7

```
>> mser_compile
```

I received these errors:

```
Creating library C:\Users\Neetika\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_JMN0MS\templib.x and object C:\Users\Neetika\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_JMN0MS\templib.exp 
erfill.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _snprintf referenced in function _mexFunction 
erfill.mexw32 : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'erfill.mexw32' failed.
Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully
Error in mser_compile (line 7)
mex('erfill.mex.c','-output', 'erfill',opts{:}) ;
```

To solve the linking problem of erfill.mexw32 i tried this command :

```
>> mex -O -largeArrayDims mser.mex.c erfill.mex.c
```

but again it gave me error saying :

```
mser.mex.c
mser.mex.c(40) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mexutils.c': No such file or directory 
C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'mser.mex.c' failed. 
Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.
```

please give a solution.

Comment: what compiler you are using?

"snprintf" is a C99 function, and "_snprintf" is a MSVC extension to C89, so it's hard to say.

Comment: If you look at the documentation page, that MSER code is considered to be deprecated.  Use the MSER implementation in the `vlfeat` package instead.

Comment: vlfeat gives a direct implementation using predefined functions. is there any other implementation for mser?